# how to set up a zend multiCheckbox form field with the checkboxes checked?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

i have this form:

```
$this->addElement ( 
            'multiCheckbox', 'servers2', 
            array (
                   'checkedValue' => '0',
                   'multiOptions' => array(
                        '11.com' => '.com',
                        '12.com' => '12.com',
                        '16.com' => '16.com',
                        '3.com' => '17.com'
                        )
            ));
```

the problem is that the `checkedValue` doesn't work for this setup, it does for a simple checkbox. I've also tried `'checkedValues' => array('1','0')`, singular or plural, 
but no end in sight.

any ideas?

THanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To mark certain checkboxes as checked, try this:

```
$multiCheckElement->setValue(array('11.com', '3.com'));

// or 

$this->addElement ( 
    'multiCheckbox', 'servers2', 
    array (
        'value' => array('11.com', '3.com'), // select these 2 values
        'multiOptions' => array(
                    '11.com' => '.com',
                    '12.com' => '12.com',
                    '16.com' => '16.com',
                    '3.com' => '17.com'
                    )
    )
);
```

See also [Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.multiCheckbox)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it had to be an array. I kept sequentially setting the value and it was only checking off the last selected value.

Comment: when I use setValue($arrayOfCheckedValues), this doesnt work in zend 2, any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

ZF2 will require you to use value_options;

```
$form->add(
        array(
            'name' => 'servers2',
            'type' => \Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox::class,
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'servers2',
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Servers 2',
                'column-size' => 'sm-10',
                'label_attributes' => array('class' => 'col-sm-2'),
                'twb-layout' => 'horizontal',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '11.com' => '.com',
                    '12.com' => '12.com',
                    '16.com' => '16.com',
                    '3.com' => '17.com'
                )
            ),
        )
    );
```

Comment: The question is about setting a tick in each checkbox that is checked. Your answer does not seem to provide that information. It only show the possible options, not the checked ones.

Comment: No, that answer was above here (the "value" key filled with an array). I'm just here to inform you that ZF2 requires the naming to be `value_options` instead of `multiOptions`.

Comment: My mistake Rob. I didn't see that the `value` attribute in @drew010's answer was the way to specify it in Zend 1. I was looking and trying for ZF2 which as you mention uses another `value_options`attribute.

Comment: Yeah I understand you took it that way, I might have formatted it a bit strange. Did it all work out for you now?

Comment: Yes it did work, and I posted my working solution here for the record.

Answer (score 0):

To specify the checked options, as seen [at](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.element.multicheckbox.html) 
use the `'selected' => true` attribute:

```
$options = array(
    array(
        'value' => '0',
        'label' => 'Apple',
        'selected' => false,
        'disabled' => false,
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'apple_option',
            'data-fruit' => 'apple',
        ),
        'label_attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'apple_label',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'value' => '1',
        'label' => 'Orange',
        'selected' => true,
    ),
    array(
        'value' => '2',
        'label' => 'Lemon',
    ),
);
```